# When should refresh and access tokens expire?

Tags: security, authentication, jwt, token

I have seen a lot of contradiction throughout my research so I'm hoping to get some more honest opinions. I am building my own authentication server, on login, the user receives an access token and a refresh token. Should the refresh token expire before, at the same time, or after the access token? Keycloak seems to do it before, however everything else seems to do it after. What is the most secure option?